# Clearing a text field value using a final-form calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I am trying to use the final-form calculator to clear a field whenever another field has changed.

[In my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-calculated-fields-forked-54dqx?file=/index.js), I have two fields. Whenever the first field changes, the second field is cleared. This is expected.

However, A problem arises when the parent component of the form is re-rendered. Each time the parent component calls to it's render function, the second field is cleared even though the first field has not changed. This can be observed by clicking the `forceUpdate` button at the top.

Is it possible to prevent the second field from clearing like this? Preferably without using `shouldComponentUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve it by moving the decorators array outside of the component.

```
const decorators = [calculator]; // declared outside of App
```

And reference the value in the form props

```
<Form
  decorators={decorators}
  ...
```